# Question about Standardization and results

Tags: regression, machine-learning, standardization

In a machine learning I've trained using standardization, do I need to re-standardize the values I'm entering to get new estimates? For example, I'm going to train a machine learning model to predict the foot number of a person's age height and weight, in this case, let's say I train by standardizing the age height and weight values for training. Assuming we get a high accuracy value after the training is over, do I need to standardize these features to estimate the foot size of a 45-year-old 1.90 m tall 87 kg person? I am trying to do something similar in this study, I get the same result no matter what I enter, for example, if I standardize [45,190,87] and enter it alone, if I enter [22,1.82,71] for another estimation, the model gives the same results. What is the reason for this? In order to prevent this, should I add these values to the data set I use and standardize that way and perform the estimation process?

[**ChatGPT content removed**]

So, I put the data I wanted to generate a new estimate on the top of the data I used for training and standardized it, then I predicted all the data and got the prediction I wanted. Now while I was writing it, I thought that I probably didn't need to predict all the data. Do you think it is the right method? Obviously, I was satisfied with the results, but I would like to take into account the opinions of knowledgeable people in the forum and make sure that what I am doing is correct. I'm open to your suggestions and criticisms, I'm a bit new to machine learning, sorry if I said something wrong.

Comment: Please refrain from posting ChatGPT content to this site. https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6422/what-to-do-about-answers-written-by-chatgpt